# WPF Change Propery after Storyboard has Run

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have the following Storyboard which is triggered like so;

```
Storyboard s = (Storyboard) myrect.FindResource("sb");
s.Begin();
```

-

```
<Storyboard BeginTime="0" Duration="Forever" x:Key="sb" >
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myrect" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="{Binding ElementName=myrect, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        Duration="0:0:0.2" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
</Storyboard>
```

But how can I then undo this (on a button press) so that I can set `myrect.Height = 0;`? I understand that this isn't working as the animation is still running. I tried `FillBehavior="Stop"` but this causes the Height to revert to 0 at the end of the animation.

I can FindResource again and stop the Storyboard but I was wondering if there was a way to tell the Storyboard to finish but leave the Height at the new value?

NOTE: The storyboard may be rerun again after this so I don't believe removing the storyboard completely is an option.

Comment: Set FillBehavior to Stop and add a Completed handler that sets the property value to the desired value.

Comment: Did you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts

Answer (score 0):

```
myrect.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, null);
myrect.Width = 0;
```